# How to convert element id in Javascript to jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i dont know, how to chance this script to jQuery, please help
JavaScript

```
function show_t(id){
    document.getElementById("hide_t_"+id).style.visibility='visible';
}
function hide_t(id){
    document.getElementById("hide_t_"+id).style.visibility='hidden';
}
```

this is div element on php, with above script

```
    <div class='item' onMouseOver="show_t('$dataBB[0]')" 
onMouseOut="hide_t('$dataBB[0]')">
```

I have trouble, when I change with this script

```
$("#show_t1"+id).mouseover(function(){
    document.getElementById("hide_t_"+id).style.visibility='visible';
}).mouseout(function(){
    document.getElementById("hide_t_"+id).style.visibility='hidden';
});
```

the *div* element for script on above is

```
<div id="show_t$dataBB[0]">
<span id='hide_t_$dataBB[0]' class='hide_input'>
</span>
</div>
```

You can see what I means in [www.tumbasklik.com](http://www.tumbasklik.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step By Step

1. There is no need of `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut` function in `.item` divs. Remove them. No need to pass `values` from `php`
2. Make your spans meaningful - instead of putting class `hide_item` to all spans, put class as `buy-option hidden`. Do all the styles to `.buy-option { /* Styles */ }` and put `.hidden { display: none; }`
3. Change jQuery code to this much only:

   ```
   jQuery(function($) {
       $('div.item').mouseover(function() {
           $(this).find('.buy-option').removeClass('hidden');
       })
       $('div.item').mouseout(function() {
           $(this).find('.buy-option').addClass('hidden');
       });
   });
   ```
4. Check [**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/OMS_/4CLAZ/) and copy paste code from respective iframes (HTML, CSS, JS)
5. Start Learning jQuery starting from [DOM traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/)

Comment: thanks so much :), can you send your file to my email arryanggaputra@gmail.com

Comment: i have see in jsfiddle.net/OMS_/4CLAZ , its working . hahaha nice.... i love ya... thanks so much

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
document.getElementById("hide_t_"+id).style.visibility='visible';
```

To

```
$("#hide_t_"+id).css('visibility','visible');
```

Your code would be.

```
$("#show_t1"+id).mouseover(function(){       
    $("#hide_t_"+id).css('visibility','visible');
}).mouseout(function(){       
    $("#hide_t_"+id).css('visibility','hidden');
});
```

**Edit**: You can change your selector to use wild cards instead of feeding id, and using class of span instead of generating the id.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/jdJ6L/)**

```
$("[id^=show_t]").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find('.hide_input').css('visibility', 'visible');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).find('.hide_input').css('visibility', 'hidden');
});​
```

Comment: how about the div element? <div id="show_t$dataBB[0]">
<span id='hide_t_$dataBB[0]' class='hide_input'>
</span>
</div>

Comment: You can use find() method of jQuery to select the elements with div like $("#hide_t_"+id).find('.hide_input') will give you span
Read more about find here, http://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: @Arry: you'll have to give more than *that* if you want us to help you resolve the problem. How is it not working? Are there any errors in the JavaScript console? Is it just doing something differently than you want, or nothing at all?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, it could just be that the solution here needs to be in a **document ready function** since the variables in the div are provided from the PHP script.

Comment: @arttronics Now I understood what you meant with "populated by PHP". Past my sleep time already, sorry. Happy new year everyone btw.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please have a look as it may help you @ArryanggaAlievPratamaputra

Comment: @DavidThomas its not working because #hide_t not showing when i try to  hover id #show_t ,

Answer (score 0):

with Jquery -

```
$("#hide_t_"+id).hide();
$("#hide_t_"+id).show();
```

Try like this-

```
$("#show_t1"+id).mouseover(function(){
    $(this).show();
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/alokan/5)

Comment: i have using this suresh, but its not useful -_-

Comment: @ArryanggaAlievPratamaputra: updated my post please try like this.

Comment: if is using $(this).show(), its didnt referer to anything id right?

Comment: @ArryanggaAlievPratamaputra: $(this) refer the same element. so i think it will work for you.

Comment: did you mean like this "$(this) is refer to all element id one group, i means in the inside div element"

Comment: @ArryanggaAlievPratamaputra: Added demo please have a look.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi http://www.mediafire.com/?bn61k7shh91h61b you can download my demo here, just 80Kb, thanks.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi please help me guys, i went confused

Comment: @ArryanggaAlievPratamaputra, Hey, I put an answer, kindly see if it works. I downloaded the zip file from mediafire and changed it to work using simple jQuery. Tell me where to upload. you can also go on the jsFiddle link and copy code from there - jsfiddle.net/OMS_/4CLAZ

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#show_t1"+id).mouseover(function(){
    $("#hide_t_"+id).css('visibility','visible');
}).mouseout(function(){
    $("#hide_t_"+id).css('visibility','hidden');;
});
```

Comment: who have problem with answer